# Remove duplicate items from array that contain the same substring

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, duplicates

I have an array containing multiple string items. all of them have a format like this:

```
code1-code2-id-
```

`code1` is different in each string. `code2` is always the same.
What I want to do is to remove the elements that have the same id.

Example:

```
const links = ["13989664-34-1-","3588867-34-1-","4757546-34-2-" ,"72469424-34-2-"]
```

desired output:

```
["13989664-34-1-","4757546-34-2-"]
```

P.S : It doesn't have to return the first duplicate or the second one. Either one is fine

I have tried this solution and was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do it

```
const links = [
  "13989664-34-1-",
  "3588867-34-1-",
  "4757546-34-2-",
  "72469424-34-2-",
];

const uniqueLinks = [];
links.forEach((link, index) => {
  console.log(index);
  const linkId = link.substring(link.length - 2, link.length - 1);
  if (index == 0) uniqueLinks.push(link);
  else if (
    !uniqueLinks.find((l) => l.substring(l.length - 2, l.length - 1) == linkId)
  ) {
    uniqueLinks.push(link);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello, questions about code that works are not really on topic in stackoverflow (improving code can be subjective, there is no definitive answer). It would be a better fit in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `findIndex` for that. Ie, keep those elements, where the search for the first occurrence of that elements's id returns the element's index. This will always keep the first element with the respective id.

```js
const links = ["13989664-34-1-","3588867-34-1-","4757546-34-2-" ,"72469424-34-2-"]
function getId(s) {
  return s.split("-")[2];
}


const filtered= links.filter((l, i) => links.findIndex(x => getId(x) === getId(l)) == i);
console.log(filtered)
```

Thus for `"13989664-34-1-"` the search for id `"1"` will return an index of `0` which is the same as the index of `"13989664-34-1-"` in the array. But when searching for the id `"1"` of `"3588867-34-1-"`, it will again return `0` (as the first element in the array has id `"1"`), but the index of `"3588867-34-1-"` in the array is `1`, thus, this element will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Using a reduce and return the values

`It doesn't have to return the first duplicate or the second one. Either one is fine`

To keep the first we can use the `??=` [nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)

To keep the last found, change `??=` to `=`

```js
const links = ["13989664-34-1-","3588867-34-1-","4757546-34-2-" ,"72469424-34-2-"]
const filtered = Object.values(links.reduce((acc,cur) => {
    acc[cur.split("-")[2]] ??= cur;
    return acc;
  } ,{})
)

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const links = ["13989664-34-1-","3588867-34-1-","4757546-34-2-" ,"72469424-34-2-"];

console.log(links.filter((item, index) => {
    return links.filter((innerItem, innerIndex) => {
        return (innerIndex < index) && (item.split("-")[2] === innerItem.split("-")[2])
    }).length === 0;
}))
```

The idea is that we use `.filter()` in a nested manner, that is, we search for items for which we search for earlier items having the same id and where we do not find such earlier items (`.length === 0`), we confirm that this is the first item having that id.

EDIT

This answer has been criticized for doing too much processing. So I have provided a code that saves the current id of the outer `.filter()` into a variable.

```js
const links = ["13989664-34-1-","3588867-34-1-","4757546-34-2-" ,"72469424-34-2-"];

console.log(links.filter((item, index) => {
    return links.filter((innerItem, innerIndex) => {
        let currentID = item.split("-")[2];
        return (innerIndex < index) && (currentID === innerItem.split("-")[2])
    }).length === 0;
}))
```

Comment: That is a LOT of processing for something so simple. For a large dataset splitting twice will have penalties. Also it is really hard to read/understand

Answer (score 0):

Once you extract the key, matching the key in an object would be faster, than looping through a new array to see if the key exists.

```js
const links = ["13989664-34-1-", "3588867-34-1-", "4757546-34-2-", "72`469424-34-2-"]
let obj = {}
let result = []
links.forEach(el => {
  let key = el.split("-")[2]
  if (!obj[key]) {
    result.push(el)
    obj[key] = true
  }
})
obj = {}
console.log("result", result)
```

Comment: Reduce does all this in one go